# Cant load data in shape tags for powerpoint add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

[stripped whining]

My current issue is that I am trying to get a list of shapes, and check the tags for each shape and if I find a specific tag, I do something with it.

This worked at one time, and I am not sure what changed to make this no longer work.

What is happening now is that I am getting the following error message while trying to read tag.value: `RichApi.Error: GeneralException`.

I have tried multiple different ways to get this data (see below), so the error has been different places.  Right now it is showing that the offending statement is `var tag = tags.getItem("mc-accessToken");`, but earlier it was at `(!tag.isNullObject)` and then `await this.replaceExistingDiagram(tag.value);` (on tag.value)

Can someone please direct me to a resource that can help!

My original code was as follows:

```
await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
      const presentation = context.presentation;
      const slides = presentation.slides.load("items");
      await context.sync();

      for(let slideIndex = 0; slideIndex < slides.items.length; slideIndex++) {
        const slide = slides.items[slideIndex];
        const shapes = slide.shapes.load("items");
        
        await context.sync();

        for (let shapeIndex = 0; shapeIndex < shapes.items.length; shapeIndex++) {
          const shape = shapes.items[shapeIndex];
          const tag = shape.tags.getItemOrNullObject(C.TokenSettingName);
          if (!tag.isNullObject) {
            shape.delete();
            await this.replaceExistingDiagram(tag.value);
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

I have made different changes to try and make sure that I am loading the properties I need
My current iteration of code looks like this (only showing changes):

```
        const shapes = slide.shapes.load('items');
        await context.sync();

       for ... {
          const shape = shapes.items[shapeIndex];
          shape.tags.load("key, value");
          await context.sync();
          
          ...
        }
```

I have also tried:

- `const shapes = slide.shapes.load('items, isNullObject');`
- `const tag = shape.tags.getItem(C.TokenSettingName);`
- `shape.load('tags');`
- `shape.load('tags');`
- `const tag = shape.tags.getItem(C.TokenSettingName); tag.load('value');`
- `shapes.load("tags/key, tags/value");`

**( I just found this: `shapes.load("items/$none");`, would I need to do something like `shapes.load("items/tags");`?)**

Comment: Your 1st point isn't really suitable for Stack. Please go to [load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/develop/application-specific-api-model#load). If you don't find it useful, scroll to the bottom of the page and create and issue with the **This page** button.

Comment: For your 2nd point, please reproduce the issue in Script Lab. Use the code that you say used to work and has stopped working. Then export the code as a gist from Script Lab and provide a URL to the gist.

Comment: @RickKirkham - link to documentation gives a 404

Comment: Im not sure what code worked. At this point I just want to get the code to work at all - At this point I am looking to understand what is the right way to get the tags for a shape

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#load

Comment: After trying so many different ways to load the tag values in ScriptLab, I finally found something that worked, and have ported it to my code.  It seems like we need to call .load() and context.sync() many times.  If you want tag values for all shapes in all slides, can you do one load call?  i.e.: slides.load("shapes/tags/value")?